# Hangman: Registering as correct after only a few correct guesses

Tags: python-3.x

When I run this, after a few correct guesses it prints `Prisoner Wins!`
Does anyone know why?

```
num_letters=int(input('How many letters?'))

word_to_guess = []
for _ in range(num_letters):
    word_to_guess.append(
        input('Input your (lowercase) letter:').lower().strip())

word_to_show = ['?', ] * num_letters
fail = 0
good = 0

while fail < 7 and good < num_letters:
    guess = input('Guess a letter...').lower().strip()
    if guess in word_to_guess:
        print('Right!')
        good += 1

        for i, letter in enumerate(word_to_guess):
            if guess == letter:
                good+=1
                word_to_show[i] = letter
    else:
        print('No.')
        fail += 1

    print(word_to_show)

print('word_to_guess', word_to_guess)
print('word_to_show', word_to_show)
if fail == 7:
    print('Executioner wins!')
else:
    print('Prisoner wins!')
```

The discrepancy is inconsistent. I tried it multiple times and it ranged from 2 to 6. One other thing: this code was provided by Ralf.

Comment: You should increment "good" exactly once for each correct letter (as you do in line 19), but you increment it one more time for each correct guess (l.16), so the while loop terminates earlier than planned. Just remove the good+=1 in line 16 and it should work.

Comment: If I do that, it only registers as 1 `good`.

Comment: did you try it?

Comment: Yes, I did. It now registers as only one `good`.

Comment: The while-loop won't terminate if good stays at 1, so i guess you mean that good now only increases by one for each correctly guessed letter? In that case, that is exactly how I think it's supposed to go. After the change, the program now works correctly for me.